# Subsetting a dataframe into an array

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, subset

Is it possible to subset a data frame into an array?
I have a huge data frame and need to create subsets to work with them. 
There is a long method where i create many variables but what about an array storing these subsets?
I want to subset based on the year(from `2004` to `2015`) and store it into an array.
Here is my code.

```
for(i in (4:15))
{
v=2004
temp<-subset(LI,format(strptime(LI[,1],"%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y")==v)
Annual_LI[i]<-temp
v=v+1
}
```

The error which appears is

> M_LI [i] < - temp :
>     Number of replacing elements is not a multiple of the length of replacement

How do i go about this?

Comment: care to share example of your data?

Comment: Are you sure you need to make all the subsets? There are several packages ('data.table','dplyr') that make performing operations per subset very easy.

Comment: Not sure what `M_LI` is but the error suggests it expects a certain size. Perhaps try using a list indexed by the year (as a string) if you must have the subsets precomputed, all to hand and in a single object .

Comment: I am sorry the error was Annual_LI[i] not M_LI[i].
an example of how LI would be is:
Date                    A values      B Values
2001-01-02          56               47
2001-01-09          26               77
2001-01-02          44               41

And so forth for 10-12 years with a values for every day